# Compare string in list

Tags: dart

I want to match two string in the same list. I want to get words from a string and insert into list. I want to remove white space and separate by commas. Then I want to check two string in that list whether match or not.

Here is my code:

```
main() {
  List<String> list = new List();
  String str = "dog , dog , cat, tiger, lion, cat";
  String strn = str.replaceAll(" " , "");
  list = strn.split(",");

  print(list.length);
  print(list);

  for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    if (list[i] == list[i+1]) {
      print("same");
    } else{
      print("not same");
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

here string only check upto length 4. and white space not removed!

Comment: What is your question? I can see that you increment `i` twice (`i++` in the for header and in its body) and that you count one too far in the loop (if i is `list.length - 1` then `list[i+1]` will throw, you just happen to dodge this by incrementing `i` twice so it never hits the value 5).

Comment: My question why it doesn't hit index 4 and 5? and why it doesn't remove white space?

Comment: The double increment of `i` answers the first question (it actually doesn't hit indices 1, 3 and 5). Also, it does remove white-space. Instead of `print(list);`, try using `print(list.join(","));`. The `List.toString` method adds comma+space between elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also noticed that in the `for` loop you are incrementing `i` twice, the second being close to the bottom. This causes `i` to skip some of the indexes, so loop looks at index 0, then 2, then 4, then it stops.

I have refactored your solution slightly. I removed the second `i++` and changed `i < list.length` to `i < list.length - 1` to skip the last item as `list[i + 1]` will throw an out of range exception:

```
main() {
  List<String> list = new List();
  String str = "dog , dog , cat, tiger, lion, cat";
  String strn = str.replaceAll(" ", "");
  list = strn.split(",");

  print(list.length);
  print(list.join('|'));

  for(int i=0; i < list.length - 1; i++){
    if(list[i] == list[i+1]){
      print("same");
    }
    else{
      print("not same");
    }
  }
}
```

The result of the loop is so:

```
same
not same
not same
not same
not same
```

You can test this out on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)